Cannot download FlutterFlow 5.0 code on VS Code
The new FlutterFlow version just released and there was suppose to be a new feature that allowed us to download code in VS Code using the FlutterFlow extension, edit the code and then push it back in FlutterFlow.
This way, we were finally able to edit the flutterFlow code.
But, when I try to use the download code feature I get a download error and I cannot even retrieve the code.
Keep in mind that I already entered my FlutterFlow account Token in VS Code settings.
Here is the error :




Thanks for your help

Did you edit other fields in the extension settings? I got this error when I filled in the optional fields (branch name etc.) in the extension settings however it worked when I reset the settings and only entered the api token (left the others blank). I'm also assuming you replace my_project_id with your actual FF project ID?

No I only edited the token field and yes I entered the correct project_id but it still doesn't works but thanks anyway for your answer.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
